# Meaning of "target" in virsh XML VM definitions

Tags: devices, libvirt

I recently found that the target=hda tag in virsh was actually not translating into guest OS (guest OS's use /dev/sdX as the disk device names, in general, it seems).

[virt-install and /dev/hda vs. /dev/sda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81817/virt-install-and-dev-hda-vs-dev-sda)

I am thus now wondering, what is the meaning of the "target dev" declarations which comprise my virt-install / virsth dumped XML files?

```xml
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
    <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
    <source file='/VirtualMachines/bthadoop-sda.raw'/>
    <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
    <alias name='ide0-0-0'/>
    <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
</disk>
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
    <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
    <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/sandbox1'/>
    <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
    <alias name='ide0-0-1'/>
    <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
</disk>
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [reference documentation](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html) for the libvirt domain XML files, specifically this section: [Hard drives, floppy disks, CDROMs](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsDisks).

> target
>
> The target element controls the bus / device under which the disk is
>   exposed to the guest OS. The dev attribute indicates the "logical"
>   device name. The actual device name specified is not guaranteed to map
>   to the device name in the guest OS. Treat it as a device ordering
>   hint.
>
> The optional bus attribute specifies the type of disk device to
>   emulate; possible values are driver specific, with typical values
>   being "ide", "scsi", "virtio", "xen", "usb" or "sata". If omitted, the
>   bus type is inferred from the style of the device name (e.g. a device
>   named 'sda' will typically be exported using a SCSI bus).
>
> The optional attribute tray indicates the tray status of the removable
>   disks (i.e. CDROM or Floppy disk), the value can be either "open" or
>   "closed", defaults to "closed". NB, the value of tray could be updated
>   while the domain is running.
>
> Since 0.0.3; `bus` attribute since 0.4.3; `tray`
>   attribute since 0.9.11; "`usb`" attribute value since after 0.4.4;
>   "`sata`" attribute value since 0.9.7

Answer (score 0):

Just agreeing with *slm*, target device depends on the driver used by host **and** guest OS. Doesn't have to match.